# How to pass data to a Ole web browser using Powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

I have created an OLE object in a window of Powerbuilder. It is created to generate a report on the data sent from Powerbuilder.
Point is that I pass the values from Powerbuilder window to the Ole web browser control via URL. The URL contains the server name as well as the data also.

Its working fine but I do not want to send the data via URL. Is there any other way to send the data from the Powerbuilder to Ole web browser control.

```
ole1 IE
IE = create ole_1

If GetContextService("Internet", iinet_base) = 1 Then

IE.navigate(ls_url)

End if
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the browser OLE control and URL. why don't you simply create a datawindow for that report and place it on the window and retrieve the data or set the data if its coming from some external source.